# how to extract substring from an environment variable

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

In postman response I have something similar to this

```
"References": [

    "Ref/6789",

    "Id/1234"
],
```

I want to set values 6789 and 1234 to different variables. I am using

```
let response = pm.response.json();

let bookref = response.References + '';

pm.environment.set("bookref", bookref);
```

// this sets bookref to Ref/6789,Id/1234

```
pm.environment.set("ref", bookref.split(',')[1]);

pm.environment.set("id", bookref.split(','));
```

Both the last 2 lines are failing with

> ReferenceError: ref is not defined.

What is missing here? I have tried using `.toString()` function as well but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```html
let ref  =  bookref[0].split('/')[1] ;
 let id = bookref[1].split('/')[1] ;


pm.environment.set("ref", ref );

pm.environment.set("id",  id );
```